# Swift mutating Function as first class value

Tags: swift, functional-programming, mutating-function

I can have a function to swap the first two elements of an array:

```
func swapFirstTwo(array: inout [Int]) {
  if array.count >= 2 {
    array.swapAt(0, 1)
  }
}

typealias Swapper = (inout [Int]) -> ()

// And I can have a variable = the function
let swapThem: Swapper = swapFirstTwo

// And it works like this:
var array = [1,2,3]
print(array)
swapThem(&array)
print(array)

// But I'm allergic to Global functions!
// It would be more swifty to have:

extension Array where Element == Int {
  mutating func swapFirstTwo2() {
    if count >= 2 {
      swapAt(0, 1)
    }
  }
}

typealias Swapper2 = (inout [Int]) -> () -> ()

// But when I do this:
let swapThemAgain: Swapper2 = Array.swapFirstTwo2
// I get the error:
// Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed; calling the function has undefined behavior and will be an error in future Swift versions

var array2 = [1,2,3]
print(array2)
array2.swapFirstTwo2()
print(array2)
// This in fact works but I've tried similar things and sometimes they appear to be unstable.
// How can I achieve doing: array2.swapFirstTwo2() without getting the error?
```

This in fact works but I've tried similar things and sometimes they appear to be unstable.
Also the compiler warning needs to be heeded.
How can I achieve doing: array2.swapFirstTwo2() without getting the warning/error?

Comment: Interesting. I understand why partial application of a *bound* method wouldn't work, that would in-effect make all value types into reference types. But an unbound function like this should be fine, from what I can tell.

Comment: @Alexander The problem is that an `inout` argument is only valid for the duration of the call, so applying `(inout [Int]) -> () -> ()` with `&array2` would give you a `() -> ()` that now has an invalid reference to `array2`. This problem will be fixed [if/when unapplied instance methods get flat signatures](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md).

Comment: @Hamish Ahhhh, brilliant! Just as I read your second sentence, I was thinking to myself "ah, so that problem will be solved with the new instance method types", and then boom, you mention exactly that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get a warning (and soon to be an error in Swift 5 mode) on:

```
extension Array where Element == Int { 
  mutating func swapFirstTwo2() {
    if count >= 2 {
      swapAt(0, 1)
    }
  }
}

typealias Swapper2 = (inout [Int]) -> () -> ()
let swapThemAgain: Swapper2 = Array.swapFirstTwo2
```

is due to the fact that `inout` arguments are only valid for the duration of the call they're passed to, and therefore cannot be partially applied.

So if you were to call the returned `(inout [Int]) -> () -> ()` with `&array2`, you would get back a `() -> ()` which now has an invalid reference to `array2`. Attempting to call that function will yield undefined behaviour, as you're trying to mutate an `inout` argument outside of the window where it's valid.

This problem will be fixed [if/when unapplied instance methods get flat signatures](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md), as `Array.swapFirstTwo2` will instead evaluate to a `(inout [Int]) -> ()`.

But in the mean time, you can workaround the issue by using a closure instead:

```
typealias Swapper2 = (inout [Int]) -> ()
let swapThemAgain: Swapper2 = { $0.swapFirstTwo2() }

var array2 = [1,2,3]
print(array2) // [1, 2, 3]
array2.swapFirstTwo2()
print(array2) // [2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Hamish - much appreciated and useful to have the link to the future fix.